# React Native: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, react-native

I just started with React native.

I've follow this article: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I run my application with command: **react-native run-android** but it show an exception:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for co
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.bu
>   >      Required by:
>   >          :abcdefgg:unspecified
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools
>   >     Could not get resource 'https:// /build/gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcente /gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'.
>   >     Connection to https://jcen
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the sta option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

How can i resolve this problem? I've read many articles here, Local Maven repository for Support Library has been installed in my computer.

Thanks very much!

Comment: i think you need to install 'Android Support Repository'.

Comment: 'Android Support Repository' is now renamed to 'Local Maven repository for Support Library' :)

Comment: Are you sure about this? I've not done native development so not sure. But in my sdk manager Android Support repository is there. And also gradle build system doesn't need maven.

Answer (score 6):

I just solve this problem this morning.
If you noticed there is a list of dependencies map defined in settings.gradle inside android folder.
Here is what I did:

1. Go to android folder
2. Run this command `./gradlew installDebug --info`

And then it will show a list of dependencies that android need. It also show which dependencies are not resolved.

In my case I'm lack of 'react-native-network-info' so all I need to do is npm install that package.

Maybe your situation will difference but I think this can help you.

Comment: It's quite late because I asked this question over a year ago (when I was new to RN). Anyway, thank you so much for your answer! It may be helpful for others later. (Anh em VN)

Comment: Wow. :D What's a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

In react-native this problem is due to flipper dependencies, it is solved by increasing its version to 0.105.0. (file: gradle.properties)